# Deploying a 'JAR' file instead of 'WAR' file for Spring-MVC and Maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jar, war

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which uses Maven. In the POM.xml I noticed that I can denote the file-type in which I can select if I want to deploy the project as a JAR or WAR. 
Mostly I select a WAR file and then deploy it in Apache tomcat. My question is, If the application is Spring-MVC based, with Spring-Security, Hibernate and other libraries, can I package it as JAR by simply denoting it in POM.xml and deploy it in Apache webserver instead of using Apache tomcat? Or do I need to make some modifications somewhere for this to work. Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Apache httpd knows nothing about how to handle jar files.

What you can do though is to provided an embedded webserver (such as jetty) in your package and define in your MANIFEST.MF file a main class that will launch it and register your application to it.
That way you can package is a an auto-executable jar, or as a war that can be run on his own or deployed in a classical webserver.

Comment: Oh, I unfortunately don't have a main class in my projects, I handle the projects landing page by RequestMapping. Is there any other simple way you know I can deploy the project as something which an Apache webserver will understand, hosting with tomcat is costly.. :-(

Comment: No. Apache Webserver will be of no help for you. Hosting that support tomcat is not that expensive. Starting at 1.99 eur/month for the cheapest I know of: http://www.ovh.com/fr/vps/vps-classic.xml